# Converting multitype column to string

Tags: pandas, string, datetime, type-conversion, nonetype

Hi I have a date row that contains the following:

- dates, type: date.datetime
- dates, type: string
- string
- None

When this row contained date.datime and strings only I used `example_row.astype(str)` to convert everything to string and without it changing the value. When I do it now it shows up empty and I have tried different options like:

```
example_row.apply(lambda x: str(x) if not pd.isnull(x) else '')
```

and like using strftime, using astype(str) without the None values, astype(str, skipna=True) and more.

How can I convert the whole row to string while keeping the date-layout?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you make an example data frame ?

Answer (score 1):

According to what you described, i brought up this dataframe :

```
data= {"A": [5, "2", pd.NA, pd.to_datetime("30/08/2021", dayfirst=True)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

All you have to do is first fill the NA / None values with :

```
df = df.fillna("")
```

Then, do what you did:

```
df = df.astype(str)
```

This should give you the following output :
[image]

Edit: Also, do not forgot to affect the value to the dataframe as the function does not change the variable in place.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort! In the end the problem turned out to be that the column names were all the same, though I have no idea why that would affect that row in a way that when converting to string, the value in that location disappears...